# MySQL java error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need help. I don't understand why i am having this error. Thank you so much.
This is a project for college, we'd be grateful.
We already tried so many things... the error is basically on the msql.. we don't know why..

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DataBase {

   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://godel.math.ist.utl.pt/proj";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "hidden";
   static final String PASS = "hidden";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;

   ArrayList <Data> l =new ArrayList <Data>();
   float Mx1=0;
   float Mx2=0;
   float Mx3=0;
   float Mx4=0;
   float Mx5=0;
   float Mx6=0;
   float Mx7=0;
   float Mx8=0;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql = "SELECT * from  Table1;";
      //sql = "SELECT * from  Table1 where Patientid=8;";
      //sql = "SELECT * from  Table1 where Patientid<8;";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      while(rs.next()){
          Data d=new Data (rs.getInt(1),rs.getFloat(2), rs.getFloat(3),rs.getFloat(4),rs.getFloat(5),
                  rs.getFloat(6),rs.getFloat(7),rs.getFloat(8),rs.getFloat(9));
          l.add(d);
          System.out.println(
                  "Patient n: "+rs.getInt(1)+
                  " x1="+rs.getFloat(2)+
                  " x2="+rs.getFloat(3)+
                  " x3="+rs.getFloat(4)+
                  " x4="+rs.getFloat(5)+
                  " x5="+rs.getFloat(6)+
                  " x6="+rs.getFloat(7)+
                  " x7="+rs.getFloat(8)+
                  " x8="+rs.getFloat(9));
      }
      //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   for(Data d:l){
       Mx1=Mx1+d.x1;
       Mx2=Mx2+d.x2;
       Mx3=Mx3+d.x3;
       Mx4=Mx4+d.x4;
       Mx5=Mx5+d.x5;
       Mx6=Mx6+d.x6;
       Mx7=Mx7+d.x7;
       Mx8=Mx8+d.x8;
       }
   Mx1=Mx1/l.size();
   Mx2=Mx2/l.size();
   Mx3=Mx3/l.size();
   Mx4=Mx4/l.size();
   Mx5=Mx5/l.size();
   Mx6=Mx6/l.size();
   Mx7=Mx7/l.size();
   Mx8=Mx8/l.size();
}//end main
}
```

ERRORS

```
Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 9 > 8. 
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds(ResultSetImpl.java:764)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5245)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5167)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getFloat(ResultSetImpl.java:2383)
    at DataBase.main(DataBase.java:47)
    enter code here
```

Comment: total how many records are there in your `Teste` table?

Comment: I subbmit the wrong code! the right one is this:

Comment: Can you add the definition of the `Teste` table? It's puzzling that the error mentions column 9 whereas your code only accesses column number 1..4

Comment: how can i do that? i just started this accont now, and i dont know how the tools work

Comment: You still need to add the table definition, as it's clearly complaining about you accessing a ninth column that doesn't exist in that table!

Comment: the table is double from  x1 to x8, but we also have id... so we shouldnt include id?

Comment: Please show the `create table` statement - if the code complains because there's no ninth column it's probably right.

Comment: the thing is: our professor gave us an example with

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with:

```
sql = "SELECT * from  Table1;";
```

you are requesting all columns from that table. After that, they will be accessible in the resultset via their position. The problem with this approach is that you depend entirely on the columns in the table not changing place - they might change place eg because the table was recreated, with fields added, removed or just changed place. So, to avoid errors later on it's always best to explicitely name the columns you want in your select statement, like this:

```
sql = "SELECT id, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8 from  Table1;";
```

That way you are sure they'll land in the correct spot and as an extra bonus, the error you will get if a field is absent will be a lot easier to understand.

As a sidenote: you really should select column names that are more informative...

Now, back to the problem at hand: if the error says that there's no ninth column it's probably right.

Comment: THANKS!! after change what you've suggested new errors appeard, and the ninth column stopped being a problem:

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

Comment: at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
 at

Comment: Well, there is no "id" column, or it has another name. As you don't need it you can - for now - just remove it from your sql statement.

Comment: where can we rate you?

Comment: You can upvote this answer, and after some time (and, if no better answer is written by another user), also accept it as an answer that solved your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/tour